# How can I get the second or first term in a map c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map which holds a pair of string and int types, and I have a list of integers. I'm iterating through the list and converting its numbers to their respective strings in the map. But it is not working. Do I need to swap string and int when creating the map, or there's another way to access the first and second term?  I know I can access the map using `map.at(string)` but I don't know whether is possible to to the same with int.

> error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const key_type& {aka const std::basic_string&}’

Here is my code:

```
map<string,int> cidades;

cidades.insert(pair<string,int>("New York",1));

list<int> l;
l.push_back(1);

printList(l);

void printList(std::list<int> lista) {    

for (std::list<int>::const_iterator iterator = lista.begin(), end = lista.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator) {
    int a = *iterator;

    string city = cidades.at(a);

    std::cout << city << ", ";
}
std::cout<<"\n";
```

}

Comment: Do you need to access your map with strings at some point ? If you do, you might need another data structure or something. If you don't, then why would you map strings to integers and not the other way around ?

Comment: It is not possible, in a `std::map::at` search by the key type in your case `std::string`

Comment: Tank you! guys, Xirema brought me up what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `std::map`, you need to address objects by their key, not by their value. If you intend to look up `string`'s via the map, then you should rewrite the definition like so:

```
map<int, string> cidades;
cidades.emplace(1, "New York"); //equivalent to the code you wrote, but shorter, higher 
                                //performance, and easier to maintain, especially if you have to 
                                //make changes like switching the key/value types.

/*...*/
string city = cidades.at(a);
```

If you absolutely need to do `string` lookups based on a `map<string,int>` object, then you'll need code that looks like this:

```
for(const auto & pair : cidades) {
    if(pair.second == a) return pair.first;
}
```

Which would be very performance-taxing and probably not a good solution, since it would fail if the map has the same int for several different strings.

Comment: that's it, I do need o look up based on this map, and the map has different int types,thank you!!